# Python eve - how to get the current user after successful authentication?

Tags: python, eve

I created an auth token class like the below, and I use `self.set_request_auth_value(user['_id'])` to set the user of this request, in some hooks I want to access this user, how can I get it ?

I tried `app.get_request_auth_value()`, but that is not it.

Token Auth class:

```
class TokenAuth(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        """ Token authentication using itsdangerous """
        # TODO: revoked access can be checked here
        # without even parsing the token
        s = Serilizer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return []
        except BadSignature:
            return []
        # Celery borker Async task test
        r = add.delay(4, 4)
        print r.id
        # use Eve's own db driver; no additional connections/resources are used
        users = app.data.driver.db['users']
        user = users.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(data.get('id'))})
        # Set the user of this request
        self.set_request_auth_value(user['_id'])
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual `auth_value` is stored in Flask's `g` object ([docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g)), as `auth_value`. So in your callback you could probably do something like:

```
import flask

user = flask.g.get('auth_value', None)
# or, alternatively:
user = getattr(flask.g, 'auth_value', None)
```

Or, to stay within Eve semantics, you could use `current_app`:

```
from flask import current_app

current_app.auth.get_request_auth_value()
```

Comment: Thank you Nicola, I found out that it was in app.auth, by the way I have a related question, in my schema I have user field not required. I set it as auth_field, then I added a hook post_POST_schema, to append the user name from auth_value, the payload was str and not json, technically no validation done, I added the user id from the auth value as a string and append it back, still not pass the validation, any thoughts on how to do this, thank you for eve and for your help.

Comment: @e-nouri what was the validation error you encountered when adding the user_id?