# Python Eve get AUTH_FIELD value inside an Event Hook

Tags: python, flask, eve

I am using [User Restricted Resource Access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access) to isolate documents between users.

Is it possible to retrieve the `AUTH_FIELD` value set during request authentication? I need to filter out only the documents for the current user when doing Pymongo queries in an Event Hook, the same way Eve does.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201456/python-eve-how-to-get-the-current-user-after-successful-authentication/35238303#35238303) helps.

Comment: Yes, this answer explains better what I wanted to achieve. I'm new to flask so I haven't expressed it in the best way. I think I need to mark my question as duplicate by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if this is the best way, but I found the value inside the flask app under `current_app.auth.get_request_auth_value()`.

Comment: Thanks this si already helpful, I want to acheive the same thing, are you able to add it to the payload and pass the validation ?

Comment: I believe the only way to add it to the payload and pass validation is using [allow_unknown](http://python-eve.org/validation.html#allowing-the-unknown) in your schema.
I used it in a database before update event hook, to filter documents, not to store it. Remember, if you are using [User Restricted Resource Access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access), you document will already have this value stored.