# Having access to request.authorization.username (BasicAuth) within Database event hooks in Python Eve

Tags: python, flask, eve

I'm trying to get access to **request.authorization.username** within the [Database Event Hook](http://python-eve.org/features.html#database-event-hooks) 'on_insert', but it doesn't seem to be trivial as no access to the request object is available.

The goal is to get the **tenant identifier** for a given username, and add it automatically every time a new document is inserted into a collection.

I'm thinking of the following options:

1. Dig into Flask and try to find where I can get this info. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35203162/1349501) without any success though.
2. Handle it as a Request event hook (on_pre_POST). I should check out how to get access to the payload.
3. Use kind of a request context, where the tenant identifier would be added after the user is authenticated and retrieved at inserting time.

What do you guys think? Thx!

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? If you are using TokenAuth, or BasicAuth you can try to set the username in the current_app configuration and access it later on the event hook.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response gcw, I'm using BasicAuth... this is what I'm trying to achieve as of now, but I'd like to have a cleaner solution. I'll come back to the question when I finalize my current analysis :)

Answer (score 1):

Eve's `BasicAuth` ([source](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/auth.py#L126)) class stores the user name in `flask.g` object ([docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g)), so all you have to do is:

```
from flask import g


def my_event_hook(..)
    username = g.get('user')
    ...
```